# How to resolve "An extension method was tried, but could not be fully constructed" when using value* extension methods?

Tags: scala, extension-methods, scala-macros, scala-3

I have the following code taken from [this repository](https://github.com/bbarker/scala-callgraph-zio).

```
package callgraph.zio

import callgraph.{CallGraph, CallGraphEvaluator}
import zio.*
import scala.quoted.*

object ZIOCallGraphEvaluator extends CallGraphEvaluator:

  type ZioAny = ZIO[Any, Any, Any]
  // for reference, see FiberContext.evaluateNow
  // e.g. https://github.com/zio/zio/blob/master/core/shared/src/main/scala/zio/internal/FiberContext.scala#L275

  inline def evaluateNow(inline io0: ZioAny): UIO[CallGraph] = ${evaluateNowImpl('io0)}  

  def evaluateNowImpl(expr: Expr[ZioAny])(using Quotes): Expr[UIO[CallGraph]] = {
    val zioAny: Option[ZioAny] = expr.value[ZioAny]
    '{ UIO.succeed(new CallGraph(${Expr(expr.show)}) {}) }
  }
```

The only addition was the line `val zioAny: Option[ZioAny] = expr.value[ZioAny]`; this line breaks compilation with this error:

```
[error] 20 |    val zioAny: ZioAny = expr.valueOrError[ZioAny]
[error]    |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[error]    |value valueOrError is not a member of quoted.Expr[callgraph.zio.ZIOCallGraphEvaluator.ZioAny].
[error]    |An extension method was tried, but could not be fully constructed:
[error]    |
[error]    |    x$2.valueOrError[zio.ZIO[Any, Any, Any]](expr)(quoted.FromExpr.StringFromExpr[T]
[error]    |      )
```

Is there a way to resolve the issue? To be clear, I'm trying to reconstruct a value of type `V` (in this case, `V` == `ZioAny`) from an `Expr[V]`.

Comment: Can you `summon` a `quoted.FromExpr.StringFromExpr[ZioAny]`? It might be that such an implicit is not available.

Comment: This appears to be the issue, yes.